# URL is not loading in WKWebView Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am trying to load url, it is not loading in `WKWebView`.
I have added transport layer security in `Info.plist`

```
NSAppTransportSecurity : Dictionary {
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads : true
NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia : true
NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent : true
NSExceptionDomains : Dictionary {
    <domain.com> : Dictionary {
        NSIncludesSubdomains : true
        NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads : true
        NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads : true
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to sort it out?

Comment: I will share url also if required.

Comment: @niut - Don't know which iOS version you are targeting, but there have been [changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats) since iOS9. Also, [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52719/xamarin-forms-webview-not-loading-url) thread may be helpful as well.

Comment: @ tomerpacific thanks ...i am Targeting 11.0 version..That solution i tried but not working anything ....should i share url?

Comment: Can you open the url in Safari? And you can provide the url.

Comment: yes...in safari it is opening

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: no sir ....still struggling with issue..It is https url only....just  {} like this curly braces showing

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** Since iOS 9, iOS will only allow your application to communicate with servers that implement best-practice security by default. Values must be set in Info.plist to enable communication with insecure servers.

**Solution:** Add the following code in your info.plist to trust your domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
      <key>tests.mettl.com</key>
      <dict>       
       <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
       <false/>
       <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
       <true/>
       <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
       <true/>
     </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: This one not working ...same {} curly braces showing